# How can I display pictures in my listview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list of requirements and each requirement has properties that I extract from a json and for the moment I think I am interested in only typeName and requisiteStatusId properties from JSON. These two are the properties of the images corresponding to that requirement type (exam, Read an article, etc.) and its current status.

I can already show images inside the listview but I have to show the images that correspond to the typeName and requisiteStatusId, for example

```
{
    "id": 1221,
    "name": "Visibility - Public Acknowledgement",
    "description": "Acknowledgement from Omar during a Q Meeting",
    "typeId": 11,
    **"typeName": "Proven XP",**
    "validationId": null,
    "skillId": 131,
    "skillName": "Visibility",
    "material": "No Material",
    "materialUrl": "#",
    **"requisiteStatusId": 4,**
    "trailName": "General Knowledge",
    "trailId": 5,
    "levelId": 1    
},
```

Dependent on these two you have to show the corresponding images, there are three states and 10 types, for now I'm showing the images directly in this way, for example:

```
 public class CustomVeggieCell : ViewCell
 {
    public CustomVeggieCell()
    {
        var image = new Image
        {

        };
        var image2 = new Image
        {
        };
        var nameLabel = new Label
        {

            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            TextColor = Color.FromHex("#FF9E9E9E"),
        };

        var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout()
        {

        };
        //set bindings

        nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name", BindingMode.TwoWay);


        image.Source = "book.png";
        image2.Source = "Palomitashida.png";
        //Set properties for desired design
        horizontalLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;

        image2.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand;
        nameLabel.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
        nameLabel.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        nameLabel.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#FF9E9E9E");
        //add views to the view hierarchy
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(image);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(nameLabel);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(image2);

        View = horizontalLayout;


    }
}
```

I do not know how to extract the property from the json or how to validate it so that using the id to extract from the json tell me what type and state is the requirement, I leave them images so that it can be a little more in context
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIW51.png)

Comment: So u wanted to extract the values from JSON or ListView.SmallImageList and LargeImageList?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I want extracting, "typeName" and "requisiteStatusId", because i need show images, according properties, well now i need know how show images dependent of the json

Answer (score 0):

Use NewtonSoft JSON from Nuget from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/). You can add that NuGet package to your project from Visual Studio by right clicking your project in solution explorer > Manage NuGet Packages.

Here is a class which I created for you requirement:

```
public class Requirement
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int typeId { get; set; }
    public string typeName { get; set; }
    public object validationId { get; set; }
    public int skillId { get; set; }
    public string skillName { get; set; }
    public string material { get; set; }
    public string materialUrl { get; set; }
    public int requisiteStatusId { get; set; }
    public string trailName { get; set; }
    public int trailId { get; set; }
    public int levelId { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the code below to deserialize the JSON like this with NewtonSoft:

```
var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Requirement>("JSON String goes here");
```

This will work with one requirement. You will probably have an array of JSON objects or some other structure so tweak the code according to your structure.

You can now use `item` deserialized above to read values from it.

For a quick test if you put your json (without the last comma and the **'s you have added) into a text file and put the text file in your bin/debug folder, then you can get the JSON deserialized like this:

```
var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Requirement>(File.ReadAllText("Json.txt"));
```

Comment: i not necessary deserialize, i can extracting the json in local variable for example: 
 UserPathContract _userPathContract = new UserPathContract();
 _userPathContract = Application.Current.Properties["UserTrail"] as UserPathContract;
var requisites = _userPathContract.Requisites
                    .Where(r => r.TrailId == _currentTrail.Id
                        && r.LevelId == _currentLevel.Id
                        && r.SkillId == skill.Id && r.RequisiteStatusId == _currentRequisiteStatus.Id);

Comment: it serve me for validation in picker changed valor, i want know how extract properties for validate the requisite and show images corresponding

Comment: well you can extract the property from the deserialized json and then use the property for showing the right image. If I understand your question correctly, the JSON will have a value that you want to use.